# ffmpeg tile image from video total image count

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to get total image count tiled?
Command I'm currently with : ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i input -vf 'scale=80:45,tile=10x10' -an -vsync 0 p%03d.png

For example, the result(image) I've gotten with this command should return result : 2

[image: exmaple image]

Comment: Insert showinfo filter before the tile, and see last n value.

Comment: @Gyan thanks, this answers my question, all I've to do now is to parse the dump and extract the n, thanks a lot!